# Dependency Injection in JSR-303 ConstraintValidator

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, bean-validation, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have the same problem that the guy from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350537/inject-service-in-constraintvalidator-bean-validator-jsr-303-spring) thread has. 
More precisely I get the following error, when trying to inject a bean in my custom validator that implements CustomValidator interface (it's a NPE when accessing the bean i wanted to inject):

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:294)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:164)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:86)
```

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Do you have a solution for this? Maybe an example? Because I tried the solutions offered on the other thread and nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post example of your validator together with the `Caused by` stack-trace. Top level exceptions are usually not so interesting. Also include your validator configuration (XML or `@Configuration` bean)

Comment: It was Caused by a NPE when accessing data from the bean I wanted to inject in the validator. I use the default validator, so I have no specific XML configuration. This is how I invoke the validator
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Class>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(object);

Comment: You should probably not use `Validation`. Just `@Autowire` `ValidatorFactory` if you want to create your validator manually. I'll put that into an actual answer :).

Answer (score 2):

You should not create validator factory on your own (`Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()`) if you want to use Spring based constraint validators.

You should let Spring autowire correct factory to your bean:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    // ... handler methods

}
```

Comment: Ok. I declared a LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean in the xml file. I wire it as you suggest but I still get NPE when calling the getValidator() method on the wired bean         Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator(); (here is the NPE)
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Class>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(object);

Comment: Pavel Horal, any suggestion?

Comment: Hm... judging on the source code it is impossible to get `null` from `LocalValidatorFactoryBean#getValidator` when using hibernate-validator. Can you share your configuration?

Comment: Yep. There is the null. I use maven as build manager, and in my pom I have these dependency declared                <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Try to debug the `getValidator` call. Spring should call Hibernate's `ValidatorFactoryImpl#getValidator` almost right away, which then should call  `ValidatorContextImpl#getValidator`, which **always returns** `ValidatorImpl`. There is no way you can get `null`, unless there is some dependency mess, which you are not aware of, or you have some agressive AOP configuration, or I don't know :).

Comment: When I load my application context I get the following error: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.validation.ValidatorFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}. But i declared the LocalValidatorFactoryBean. And I try to inject it in a ValidationFactory instance as you suggested.

Comment: Can you please share Spring configuration (XML or @Configuration). Where is your validator bean, where are you trying to inject it, ...