# Custom form validation in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation, custom-validators

I am working on a spring boot application and I have a password reset form. I am using a class like this to validate the inputs.

```
public class PasswordResetForm {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=6, message="must be at least 6 characters")
    private String password;

    private String passwordConfirm;

    //Getter and Setters
}
```

So, I now want to validate if the fields passwordConfirm and password are equals, I searched all over but could not find how to add a custom validation in this case. So, how do I add custom validation for other fields?

My controller's action looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/password-change/{id}-{tokenNumber}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changePassword(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String tokenNumber, @Valid PasswordResetForm form, BindingResult formBinding, Model model) {

    if (formBinding.hasErrors())
        return "change-password";

    //Other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

or if you wanna validate simply only this (passwordConfirm and password are equals) case.

you can use @AssertTrue.

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isDifferentPass() {
    return !password.equals(passwordConfirm);
}
```

if these two fileds are same , then your controller's BindingResult has error

Comment: `@AssertTrue` (and `@AssertFalse`) works for me! Anyway, I recommend change this expression by a more simple one (to much unnecessary boolean chaining in your expression): `@AssertTrue public boolean isEqualPass() { return password.equals(passwordConfirm); }`

Comment: Another tip for this: to customize the error message to display to the user, just use the "message" property of the annotation: `@AssertTrue(message = "Passwords doesn't match")`, and if you have i18n configured in your Spring project, you can locale the message in your `messages_xx.properties` file with the key _"AssertTrue" + "." + [Java bean name of the validation method]_. In the above example the key/value will be: `AssertTrue.equalPass=Passwords doesn't match`

Answer (score 4):

For your needs, you could consider creating a custom @Constraint. You would first create the constraint annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface MyConstraint {
}

And then the constraint validator:

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;

public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator {

    @Autowired;
    private Foo aDependency;
    ...
}
```

You can find additional reference for this here:
[Dependency Injection in JSR-303 Constraint Validator with Spring fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526620/dependency-injection-in-jsr-303-constraint-validator-with-spring-fails)

And on the Spring Docs:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Validated annotation for forcing validation of @RequestParam and @PathVariable. @Valid is for forcing validation of @RequestBody