# For 400 Bad Request not getting proper error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Our controller looks like this -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="api")
@Validated
public class SampleController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void test(
        @RequestParam(value = "testCode",required=true) String merchantCode
        ) throws Exception{
    System.out.print("This is Test");
}
}
```

Here if we do not specify the required parameter "testCode" in our request we get "400 Bad Request", but the message section of the error response remains blank.

Response we are getting -

```
{"timestamp":1592441286607,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/test"}
```

But expected is -

```
{"timestamp":1592441286607,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required String parameter 'testCode' is not present","path":"/test"}
```

We are using below Spring dependencies -

```
<spring-boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<spring-framework.version>5.2.6.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

What I have seen is for this we are getting MissingServletRequestParameterException, but in the exception the message is coming as blank("").

Comment: If you want a custom message you will probably have to create your custom validator. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823263/custom-validation-for-requestparam-doesnt-work-with-spring-mvc

Comment: No, not custom message actually. What I am saying is the message section is blank it self. Am expecting default message here.

Comment: The same code is working in spring boot version 2.2.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just updated the bootstrap.yml with `server.error.include-message=always`. It appears from Spring 2.3.0 the default behavior of Spring has changed. We can refer the following link from more details https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content

Answer (score 1):

Configuration in application.yml

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-stacktrace: on_trace_param
    include-exception: true
```