# input validation using custom validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

Custom annotation, as defined https://dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303

Can we use @Capitalized annotation in controller?

e.g.

```
 @RestController

public class Abc {

@RequestMapping(value="/abc", method=RequestMethod.POST)

public String abc(@Capitalized @RequestParam(value="abc") String abc) {



}

}
```

I used in this way, but it is not working. Any idea why it is not working?

Thanks,

Comment: try adding @Validated in your class Abc

Answer (score 0):

Add `Parameter` `ElementType` in annotation target, then it will work.

E.g.:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
```

Comment: Sachin, Does it need any config change to work like other JSR validation works e.g. Min, Size etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that @Capitalized is:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CapitalizedValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Capitalized {

    String message() default "should be capital";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and you have a constraint validation impl as:

```
public class CapitalizedValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Capitalized, String> {

    private String message;
    @Override
    public void initialize(Capitalized constraintAnnotation) {
        message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        String inUpperCase = value.toUpperCase();

        if (inUpperCase.equals(value)) {
            return true;
        }

        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message);

        return false;
    }

}
```

Then try this with you're controller:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@Capitalized @RequestParam("content") String content) {
        return content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have same setup as u mentioned. But its not working

Comment: i found some link regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526620/dependency-injection-in-jsr-303-constraint-validator-with-spring-fails/27824912#27824912).... Not getting why bean config needed?

Comment: Could you include the version of dependencies in your question? ie spring-boot, hibernate-validator version?

Answer (score 0):

After including below code in Application.java, Its working fine.

```
@Bean
    public Validator validator() {
return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
 }

  @Bean
   public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
return methodValidationPostProcessor;
```

}