# Configuring spring validation and hibernate validation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, validation, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

Problem already solved here but didn't work for me (not same spring boot version i guess) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526620/dependency-injection-in-jsr-303-constraint-validator-with-spring-fails)

Trying to code a custom constraint validator, to check whether account email exists before persisting.

```
@Email
@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueCompteEmailValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface UniqueCompteEmail {

    String message() default "{com.mssmfactory.bacsimulator.uniquecompteemail.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class UniqueCompteEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueCompteEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private CompteRepository compteRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && this.compteRepository.findByEmail(value) == null;
    }
}
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@Configuration
public class OtherConfigurations {

    //----

    @Bean
    public Validator validator(@Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure()
                .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
                .buildValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

        return validator;
    }
}
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mssmfactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>bacsimulator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bacsimulator</name>
    <description>BAC Simulator</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My problem is that private CompteRepository compteRepository always contains null, and from my stacktrace, i can see that it's being instanciated by hibernate-validation instead of being instanciated by spring and used by hibernate.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changed hibernate's bean validator factory by this @Component class and now it works so well

```
@Component
public class ValidatorAddingCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    private final ObjectProvider<javax.validation.Validator> provider;

    public ValidatorAddingCustomizer(ObjectProvider<javax.validation.Validator> provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        Validator validator = provider.getIfUnique();

        if (validator != null) {
            hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution similar for non Spring boot? I am using Spring Framework 5, Hibernate 5, and Hibernate Validator 6. I've tried a lot of solutions found in Stackoverflow and nothing works yet.

Comment: To be honest i don't know i always work with spring-boot :/

Comment: Amazing.  I've been hitting my head against this one off and on for weeks!

Comment: @Mssm Bro, I have followed your approach. But when I am trying to save my entity, my validator's `isValid` method is being called **repeatedly** resulting in stackoverflow error. What am I doing wrong here? https://friendpaste.com/6ppeO6IeXz2lr4D55QDilU

Comment: @Mssm Here is the stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896519/making-database-call-inside-isvalid-method-of-custom-constraintvalidator-is

Comment: @JoeA If helps, the thing you want to eventually tweak/fix is the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean; You can set the value above in it's jpaProperties member

Comment: @JoeA did you ever figure out how to do this without spring boot?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty i had the same problem. In my case i had a custom validator on the whole entity that had to check that no overlapping periods (start and end dates) would be persisted. I figured (can someone confirm this theory ) that when using a repo in the validator impl.  spring does also return value validation which causes the stackoverflow. Same goes for entityManger bean and it's query methods. I therefore resorted to query with an injected JdbcTemplate. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is because the `@Autowired` annotation is not working for you when you autowire `CompteRepository.class`.You can autowire components in your validation class but make sure that you use spring to create the validator bean otherwise the bean injection won't work as manually creating validator bean using valdiation factory (**Hibernate Validator as reference implentation**) **does not inject dependencies into ConstraintValidator instances**.

So, you cannot use the validator factory to create the validator instance , instead autowire it and everything should work.

```
@AutoWired
Validator validator;
...

validator.validate(book);
```

Comment: I'm using annotations to validate java pojo fields obtained throw a remote access (basiclly a post request) to an exposed rest repository, i'm not the one who has to call validator.validate(entity), it's called by the validator...

Comment: Instead of configuring the validator bean yourself, can you try letting spring handle it .

Comment: If i'm not configuring my validator anymore, i just configure hibernate validator factory so that hibernate doesn't instanciate validators but uses validators that spring intanciated and which are in the the spring context