# Spring Boot Custom Validator autowired field is null

Tags: spring-boot, javax.validation

I am using Spring Boot **2.2.4.RELEASE** and I have this custom validator with an autowired service.

```
@Component
public class CompanyRequiredValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CompanyRequired, Company> {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CompanyRequired constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Company company, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return company != null && companyService.findByCompanyName(company.getCompanyName()) != null;
    }
}
```

My validation configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationProstProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }
}
```

No matter what I've tried the autowired field returns null. The things I've tried:

https://medium.com/@ssscripting/getting-autowired-fields-to-work-with-constraintvalidators-in-spring-boot-74424d5b0aaa

[Autowired gives Null value in Custom Constraint validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958145/autowired-gives-null-value-in-custom-constraint-validator)

[Configuring spring validation and hibernate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782292/configuring-spring-validation-and-hibernate-validation/56784106#56784106)

Comment: Can you please also post stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/samindaperamuna/457b8a2c44ab75b2a786e9215763666e

Comment: It looks like your companyService is not being injected. Have you tried to put debug and validate loading of classes ?
logging.level.org.springframework=debug might be handy.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this. Stuck with the same issue.