# Spring Data recursive validation

Tags: java, spring-data

Does this type of validation work?

Annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface UniqueEmail {
  public String message() default "Error message";
  public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      return userService.isEmailUnique(value); // read as a call to userRepository.findByEmail(emailAddress)
  }
}
```

And the entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
  ...
  @UniqueEmail
  private String email;
}
```

It fails because of the recursive calls between `isValid()` method and `userRepository.findByEmail()`. It this correct behavior? Does the `findByEmail` always create a new User and apply the validation on it?

**update**:
A part of the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
...
(many times)
...
UserService.isEmailUnique(UserService.java:84)
...
UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:29)
UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:13)
```

The property `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` resolves this. But still it was not even a `double validation`.

Comment: can you please share the stack trace or the precise error message?

Answer (score 0):

Answering on my own question.

Thanks for this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62900295/4207793):

> In validation, you are doing a query on the same entity which means before doing the query, hibernate need to flush what is queued in your session.

In other words if I got it right, in this case hibernate saves before the validation with it's query.

So I've added the same propagation for my method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
```

It works.
Also I don't need to keep the `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use find with entities just to check if an email address exists in

```
userService.isEmailUnique(value)
```

Why don't you create a method:

```
int countByEmail(String email)
```

Comment: In my case I had to find a user in both cases: when I `post/create new` , `patch/edit existing user`. So besides the email I also checked the `id` (or does the user exist).

Comment: But this can be all done in one query. no need to load an entity